# Wordpress. Add a word to permalinks, just in some posts

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm new in the world of Wordpress.

I need to add a word into the urls (permalinks) in my web. That word could be a category name or a static word, but I need it appears just in some cases, not of all.

```
in some cases: /%postname% 
in other cases: /%category%/%postname% 
or even: /word/%postname%
```

so, in 'Permalink Settings' option, the custom configuration: `/%postname%/%category%/` is not valid or enough for my case.

I know that exists plugins for mange urls in a way complex in Wordpress but I would prefer to do without them. but if there is no other way I would like to know which one you'll recommend me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup your categories in your posts in such a way as to accommodate this using using a parent/child/grandchild method for /%category%/%postname%

So if you have a category 'Dogs'you could give it a child category 'Alsatian' and a grandchild category 'German Dogs' to get 'www.yoursite.com/dogs/alsatian/germandogs/postname'.

So when you create your post you just assign your desired categories to the post to generate the URL you want.

If you wanted a link that was just 'www.yoursite.com/germandogs/postname' you would have to create a new top level category of 'German Dogs' and assign the post to the top level instead of the grandchild category.

This is admittedly janky and I don't really recommend it as your categories may well become unmanageable over time if you have very many of them but it would ultimately serve your purpose. It is far better to initially setup a logical tree of categories for your content and stick to it.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand well. In some cases I want the url to be formed only with the article, just after the root. eg: ```site.com/%postname%```. But, although I do not select any category for the post, the system adds the category 'Uncategorized' to the URL. Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately this is a standard defualt feature feature and expected behaviout for wordpress, the only thing to do here is to assign a category.